# ArgumentError: Relation#count does not support finder options anymore. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I recently upgraded my project from rails3 to rails4. I have below code in my model and it fails in rails 4

```
test_count  = count(:all, :joins => joins, :conditions => conditions, :distinct => true)
```

The above line of code gives following error.

```
ArgumentError: Relation#count does not support finder options anymore. Please build a scope and then call count on it or use the activerecord-deprecated_finders gem to enable this functionality.
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error in rails 4?

Thank you

Comment: Try changing it to `test_count  = (:all, :joins => joins, :conditions => conditions, :distinct => true).count`

Comment: @pavan suggestion is best, and as the error text itself suggests you can add to your gemfile `gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders', require: 'active_record/deprecated_finders'` and that should also fix the issue.

Comment: @pavan Thank you for the response. This solution still fails because this syntax is no longer supported in rails 4.

Answer (score 2):

I think your query translates to this:

```
joins(joins).where(conditions).distinct.count
```

Have a look at the Rails Guide about the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).